NavParams has been deprecated in favor of using Angular’s input API
I am getting this message in the console:

[Ionic Warning]: NavParams has been deprecated in favor of using Angular’s input API. Developers should migrate to either the @Input decorator or the Signals-based input API.

I searched everywhere and there is no working sample of using @Input decorator instead of NavParams to pass data to the modal component.
Edit:
I want to pass data to the modal component using componentProps of ionic ModalController.

You not looking enough - https://angular.dev/guide/components/inputs

I have said that @Input decorator does not work with componentProps of ionic ModalController. It is proper to pay more attention to the question!!

Here is what I am testing right now and it works with the below ionic and angular
@ionic/angular 8.2.6
@angular/cdk 18.1.4
Main page
async openGEmodal( ) {
 const modal: HTMLIonModalElement =
  await this.modalController.create({
  component: ModalgePage,
  cssClass: 'largeModal',
  componentProps: { GEtype: true } // I am using true, but you can use any thing you wish
}); 
modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) =>{
  if(data.data !== ''){ console.log(data) }
});
await modal.present();
}

Modal page
//old
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';

GEtype: any;  
this.GEtype = this.navParams.get('GEtype');

// new
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

  export class SomeClassPage {
    @Input() GEtype: any; // this becomes this.GEtype console.log will show true


Does not seem to work for signal inputs...  const popover = await this.popoverController.create({         component: MoreOptionsComponent,         componentProps: {props: props},      then in the component  public props = input<any>();    This input is always undefined.

We are using same pattern suggested by Thomas above. It works when the component property names are same as the one declared in the target modal.
This works:
@Input() propertyName: any;
If you want to rename, you would need to use an Input "alias:" (see https://angular.dev/api/core/Input)
